# Should the migrations directory in a Django project should be pushed to the git repo?

Tags: django, git, django-migrations

In a Django project, when models are changed, the migrations file will be changed. If I add the migrations directory to git, this will raise conflicts for others. If I don't add it, sometimes this will raise a server error when migrated. How do you solve this？

Comment: Why would it raise conflicts? Everyone should commit their migrations, and run everyone else's.

Comment: eg: I pull the code and make migrations, one not null field reminds me to add a default value, at this time, others may have added a different value

Comment: But that's exactly why you *should* commit the migrations. You shouldn't be running makemigrations on someone else's code; *they* should have run it and made the migrations which include the defaults, you just need to run theirs.

Comment: In our team we always exclude migrations folders, during pull we will sort out the conflicts like different default value, discuss the differences in model then apply migrations.we never push migrations to stage and prod servers.

Answer (score 3):

From Django [migrations docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/).

> The migration files for each app live in a “migrations” directory inside of that app, and are designed to be committed to, and distributed as part of, its codebase. You should be making them once on your development machine and then running the same migrations on your colleagues’ machines, your staging machines, and eventually your production machines.

This is one way that you should use Django migrations with VCS. This way it would make consistency across the different machines and database and it will also prevent merge conflicts.

Comment: Is this kind of conflict common that two people simultaneously modify a model, or just give a different default value when make mgirations?

Comment: yes its one of the conflicts that occur in managing migrations in VCS. @guangyao